# RestKit 0.20 mapping string array

Tags: objective-c, json, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

So after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15379552/mapping-a-json-array-of-unnamed-values-with-restkit-0-20), I do not see how my case is any different, but the proposed solution just doesn't seem to work in RestKit 0.20.3

For the following json:

```
{
   "photos": [
      "872ac577-3f31-47a0-966e-6f2ed2fbabcd"
     ],
   "imageUrl": [
      "http://domain/WebAPI/FileUpload/10232013629_21382571406.439790.jpeg"
     ]
}
```

Mapping into the following object:

```
@class Picture, Site, Survey;

@interface Job : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * jobId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * jobName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * jobStatusId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * jobStatus;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * projectId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * projectType;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * siteId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *surveys;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *photos;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *createdDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Site *site;
@end
```

Where `photos` is a `Picture` object that looks like this:

```
@interface Picture : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * data;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * photoId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * pictureLoc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * imageUrl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Job *job;
@property (nonatomic, retain) QuestionAnswer *question;
@end
```

I want to map the `photos` and `imageUrl` into the `Picture`'s `photoId` and `imageUrl`, respectively. I thought I could use the following in my `Job`'s mapping:

```
RKEntityMapping *ret = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Job" inManagedObjectStore:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore ];

[ret addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary: @{
                                           @"photos": @"photos.photoId",
                                           @"imageUrl": @"photos.imageUrl",
                                           }];
```

However, the mapped `Job` always ends up with nothing in the `photos` property.

I know that I am doing all the in-between steps correctly (like actually using `ret` for the mapping), as the JSON is a snippet that contains many other keys I am able to map with no problem. What am I doing wrong? please tell me

**EDIT**

Changed the mapping code as per Wain's answer:

```
RKEntityMapping *ret = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Job" inManagedObjectStore:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore ];
RKEntityMapping *subMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Picture" inManagedObjectStore:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore ];

[subMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary: @{
                                           @"photos":@"photoId",
                                           @"imageUrl":@"imageUrl"
                                           }];


[ret addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping
                         relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:nil 
                         toKeyPath:@"photos" 
                         withMapping:subMapping]];
```

And now I get a `Picture` object added, but with `nil` for `photoId` and `imageUrl` (and yes, I checked to make sure I have the spelling and capitalization correct for the JSON keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `photos` never has anything in it is that your mapping doesn't tell it to create a new object.

The problem is how you could tell it to create a single object and set both of the parameters into it. The problem is because you have 2 different arrays. The JSON I would expect you to have is 1 array which contains dictionaries with all of the details for that particular entry. RestKit can process both of the arrays but it would result in 2 distinct `photo` objects being created. To do this you need a second mapping with a `nil` key path and a relationship from `ret` to that new mapping.

An alternative could be to change the `Job` object so that it has 2 transformable (or transient) properties which are `NSArray`s. If you set `ret` to just map `@"photos" : @"photos"` and `@"imageUrl" : @"imageUrl"` then RestKit will map all of the data, just not into a `photo` object. You can then mutate this data after the mapping has completed if you want to...

Comment: still not able to capture the values, see above. As a side note, if there are 4 objects in `photos`, only 1 `Picture` is created

Comment: The change you made isn't what I suggested - because it won't work. RestKit can't map multiple arrays in that way. What you have could be made to work for the photo id but not that and the image url. The only sensible approach is to change the JSON or map the arrays to array properties in the `Job` entity.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up having the JSON changed to combine the `photoId` and `imageUrl` arrays into one array of objects with `photoId` and `imageUrl` as properties